# os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))でエラーが出ます

Tags: python

下記のコード**os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))というところで　NameError: name '__file__' is not defined**というエラーが出ます
どうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import string
import requests
import collections
import io
import gzip
import tarfile
import urllib.request
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Comment: このコードをどうやって実行しましたか?

Comment: anacondaのjupyternootbookで実行しました。ファイルはデスクトップのあるフォルダのなかのファイルです。

Comment: tensorflow用の仮想空間のjupyternootbookです

Answer (score 5, accepted):

__file__はmoduleとして呼ぶか、scriptとして実行したときじゃないと定義されません。
なので、notebook上で__file__は使えません。
[同じような質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125532/file-does-not-exisit-in-jupyter-notebook)があったので転載しておきます。
__file__等が定義されているかは、print(globals())してみるとわかります。